# Python: Recursivly get the length of file path

Tags: python

Trying to recursively scan a given directory and get the length of the file or directory path not the file or directory size

If the length is more than say 35 characters, Just to test, output the path and length to a log file

If Directory Path is > 35 then little point traversing down further

```
import sys
import os


path = sys.argv[1]
Log = path + "\\PathToLongLog.txt"
fname = []

# Check if path exits
if os.path.exists(path):
    print ("Directory exist")
    for root,d_names,f_names in os.walk(path):
        print (root, d_names, f_names)
        for f in f_names:
          fname.append(os.path.join(root, f))

#print("fname = %s" %fname)
    
for fp in fname:
  Len = len(fp)  
  if Len > 35:
    print("fname = %s" %fname, " Lenth ", str(Len) )
    msg ="fname = " + str(fname) + " Lenth " + str(Len)
    with open(Log, "a") as LogFile:
      LogFile.write(msg + "\n")
```

Expected output would be 1 line for each file

```
D:\Path\To\Very Long File\Or Directory\My File.txt  Length 50
```

What I'm getting is

```
fname = ['D:\\Path\\To\\Very Long File\\Or Directory\\My File.txt', 'Path\\To\\File1.ext', 'Path\\To\\File2.ext',etc] length 50
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Every place you have `fname` (the list of long names) in that final loop, you should instead have `fp` (the particular element from that list that you're currently iterating).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to log the file name but you are actually logging the `fname` variable which is a list of all files.

You can change the code to log the 'fp' variable instead of the 'fname' and it will work:

```
for fp in fname:
    Len = len(fp)  
    if Len > 35:
        print("fname = %s" %fp, " Lenth ", str(Len))
        msg = "fname = " + str(fp) + " Lenth " + str(Len)
        with open(Log, "a") as LogFile:
            LogFile.write(msg + "\n")
```

Comment: Thanx I got it from the comment above. Can this be adjusted so it stops scanning if Path of directory tree reaches the cut of length (>35) but continue with other branches?